# Bearer Token working on Postman but not on localhost

Tags: angular, token, postman, angular-http, bearer-token

I am trying to make a request in Angular with authorization with a bearer token. If I make the request in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), it works. But if I make it from Angular, it gives me the [`401 Unauthorized`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) http error.

I am sure that the [`localstorage.getItem('auth_token')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) is returning the right token, because I have logged it before to check.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
    Authorization: 'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('auth_token')})
  };
```

This is the request I am trying to make that works on postman :

```
 getProducts(): Observable<string[]> {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));
    return this.http.get<string[]>(this.productsURL)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched products')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getProducts', []))
      );
  }
```

Comment: Show us rest of the code? From this sample you said that `.getItem` for sure returns the right result and that's it, so from your cample it looks ok. It'd also appear you're using Anular not AngularJS as `HttpHeaders` object lives in Angular.

Comment: Errors in console? Perhaps where you make the call?

Comment: I've added the request code.

Comment: Thanks, see below.

Comment: Hey @FranciscoBarril, that's not `angularjs`, please remove that tag. This tag is reserved for Angular v1, for everything above we're using the `angular` tag. If you want to know more about tags, just click one and have a look on the description.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the fact you're not using the created headers.

Your code should look like this:

```
return this.http.get<string[]>(this.productsURL, httpOptions)
.pipe(
   tap(_ => this.log('fetched products')),
   catchError(this.handleError('getProducts', []))
);
```

Notice the `.get` constructor - apart from passing the URL, it also passed the `httpOptions` object you created the the bearer token in.

Comment: @FranciscoBarril Pleasure is all mine.